# Algebra: Inequality in interval $[0, 1]$ (Junior Serbian Mathematical Olympiad 2014)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for real numbers $a,b,c,d,e$ which belong to the interval $[0, 1]$ this always holds: $$(1+a+b+c+d+e)^2 \ge 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2)$$
When are the two sides of inequality equal?

Comment: For the second question, we have$$(1+1+0+0+0+0)^2=4(1^2+0^2+0^2+0^2+0^2)$$

Comment: square it and simplify

Comment: I have already tried that and couldnt get anything out of it

Answer (score 2):

hint: $0\le x \le 1 \implies 0\le x^2 \le x \le 1, (1+s)^2 \ge 4s, s = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2$. Let $x = a, b, c, d, e$ and add up.

Comment: Brilliant! If we take $s = a + b + c+ d +e$ that means  $$(1+a+b+c+d+e)^2 \ge 4(a+b+c+d+e) \ge 4(a^2 + b^2+ c^2 + d^2 + e^2)$$

Comment: but LHS in the brackets without square

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+a+b+c+d+e)^2-4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2)\geq$$
$$\geq(1+a+b+c+d+e)^2-4(a+b+c+d+e)=$$
$$=(1-a-b-c-d-e)^2\geq0$$